# Installed latest react, npm-start gives Error: Cannot find module 'postcss-safe-parser'

Tags: node.js, reactjs, installation

Any one faced this issue.. OS is windows 10

When i enter on powershell :

> '\react\story1> npm start'

it throws the following error :

> internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:834   throw err;   ^
>
> Error: Cannot find module 'postcss-safe-parser' Require stack:
>
> - C:\Users\Vijay\Desktop\Personal\Learning\react\story1\node_modules\react-scripts\config\webpack.config.js

Any help would be good

Comment: I am having the same problem...

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same error and it is fixed once I upgraded my node version.